# How to Set Values in a Request Scope Bean in Spring Boot Application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In my application I want to create a request scoped Bean for storing logged in user details and instantiate it from inside my JWT token verification filter since I'm already querying the record there. But, I don't know what is the best way to do it. One option I have to directly update values of the bean, but not sure if that's a good approach.

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public AppUser loggedInUserDetails() {
   return new AppUser();
}
```

**Request Filter:**

```
@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    final String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

    String username = null;
    String jwt = null;

    if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
        jwt = authorizationHeader.substring(7);
        username = jwtUtil.extractUsername(jwt);
    }

    if (username != null) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        // Here I want to update the bean
        .....
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

If there is any better way to instantiate this bean then please suggest.

I'm using Spring Boot v2.4.2

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add some logic on the JWT (like denying invalid requests and things like that) the only viable solution is the one you propose,
if you don't care about doing that things you could also have the request injected into the bean and read it directly into the bean

As you probably know just add

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```

and reuse the code you now use in the filter

bye

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you please explain by adding "private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;" how it will set the value in loggedInUser Bean?

Comment: If You have a request scoped bean,this Bean is created at every request so if You have injected current Request inside bean you can in build that object inside loggedInUserDetails method because is called every time

Comment: As you can see in my filter I already have request object so no need to auto wire, but how to set the value of loggedInUserDetails?